# multi textarea by jodit

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, jodit

I have more than 15 editors and want to display them on one page (HTML/CSS/JS).
This Jodit only works with one editor, but it does not work with more than one editor.
I want all editors to work.

See this sample code : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/dj4ghzLw/10/)

```
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>

...

<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
<textarea class="email_content"></textarea>
```

```
var editor = new Jodit(".email_content", {
  "toolbarButtonSize": "small",
  "enter": "DIV",
  "buttons": "undo,redo,|,bold,strikethrough,underline,italic,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,align,"
});
```

Is there a code that works in more than one editor?

Comment: I would think you need to initialise a new jodit editor for each text area. See this article, it's about disabling multiple but does show how to enable multiple ("new" function): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764475/disable-multiple-jodit-editors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var editors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.editor'));
editors.forEach(function (textarea) {
var editor = new Jodit(textarea, {
  "toolbarButtonSize": "small",
  "enter": "DIV",
  "buttons": "undo,redo,|,bold,strikethrough,underline,italic,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,align,"
    });
});
```